# When battling Teams are balanced?

Tags: skullgirls

I read that when selecting the number of characters for a team there's a description that says about the number of characters the characters will be more powerfull.

But how is that mesured?
It's something like this:

1 Character - 300% health

2 Characters - 150% & 150% health

3 Characters - 100%, 100% & 100% health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in both health *and* damage per hit.

You can see the full comparisons on a [Wiki-page here](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Skullgirls/Game_Elements/Life_and_Damage). (Data may be outdated, if the balance has been or will be tweaked, but I doubt it's going to be a big difference).

As there are 6 different team veriations, 1v1, 1v2, 1v3, 2v2, 2v3 and 3v3, there are a lot of different numbers to thorw around. But, in uneven situations, the boosts are surprisingly consistant.
I'm comparing these numbers to a simple 1v1 health and damage values.

- In 1v2 and 1v3, the **one** always gets boost of 105% (so, over doubling) in health and 45% in damage
- In 2v1 and 2v3, the **two** always gets boost of 15% in health (per character, *total* boost of 130%) and 30% in damage
- In 3v1 and 3v2, the **three** never gets any boosts (per character, *total* healt is boost of 200%)
- 1v1 and 2v2 are fought with normal numbers. In 3v3 both teams get a boost of 15% in health (per character) and 30% in damage

Teams of two or three also get the added benefit of extra moves, like Ensambles, Blockbuster Sequels and Stunt Doubles, which solo characters can't use, as well as slight health regen (to a point) while Tagged Out.